# A thing whose name is hard to track down

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word/phrase for *a thing whose name is hard to track down*?

Sometimes there is a concept which I believe must have a name, but I can't find that name; it's hard to track down ; I don't know what to search for in Google but I suspect once I have the word I 'll be able to glean information on it.

E.g., this Bible quote:

> And Joshua, and all of Israel with him, took Achan the son of Zerah, and the silver, and the garment, and the wedge of gold, and his sons, and his daughters, and his oxen, and his asses, and his sheep, and his tent, and all that he had.

... is using a lots of repeated '*and*'s presumably for emphasis and I know there must be a name of that literary device; I sort of understand the concept, but I just can't put my finger on the word for it.  Googling for *"repeated and"* can send me down rabbit holes. From [here](http://literarydevices.net/polysyndeton/), I eventually learn the term in this instance is **polysyndeton**, and armed with that word, it's easy to get find out more.

Example sentence:

> I'd like to know what is the literary device being used in the quote but it's a  _______.

Comment: I hope somebody gives an answer because I automatically keep reading your question again and again as "Is there a better word/phrase for a thing -which- is hard to track down". And keep repeating "elusive" to myself. I can't stop and it is annoying. It is not elusive for sure. Subtle? My head...

Comment: @Grizzly Good. Turn it into an answer, if you have the inclination.

Comment: @RichardKayser It is OK. Any other words that come to mind however?

Comment: @Grizzly I'll think on it. But it's a word. Thx.

Comment: @RichardKayser Poly-**and**-ry :-) Sorry, couldn't resist it.

Comment: @BoldBen If I understand you correctly, you must be a malefactor. :-)